# Derivation of the Hubble constant from the cosmic microwave background

Tags: cosmic-microwave-background

In the paper which presents the results of the Planck measurement (DOI: 10.1051/0004-6361/201321591) the Hubble constant is a derived parameter. How does this derivation work? Moreover, how does the Hubble constant change if we use cold dark matter with a non-zero pressure?